# DRF APIClient request session

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to put a token into request.session and then get it from my code

```
request.session.get('id_token')
```

How to do this using drf `APIClient()`? I have tried this

```
    self.client = APIClient()
    self.client.session['id_token'] = 'some key'
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Session Ids are created on authentication and sent to the client. The client can then send them on subsequent requests as part of the header

The DRF APIClient inherits the Django Client class so you can initialize it with headers

```
apc = APIClient(SESSION_ID='ljw3r23j-slzljsdf')
```

And then in your backend code where you have access to your request, you can access it via either `.headers or .META` attributes. This will depend on your version of Django

Django 2.2

```
session = requests.headers.get('SESSION_ID')
```

< Django 2.2

```
session = request.META.get('SESSION_ID')
```